# How to normalize values in XArray?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, python-xarray

I want to standartise time series data stored as XArray as the default format I'm getting from Sentinel-1 API.

For dev purpose, I converted the data in DataFrame to XArray as shown below.

My data:

```
rvi_df_t.head()
0   1   2   3   4   ... 595 596 597 598 599
period  metric                                          
1   rvi 0.368761    0.314016    0.769136    0.789736    0.353613    ... 0.639858    0.232703    0.361030    0.325893    0.423962
2   rvi 0.852262    0.707968    0.250090    1.194124    0.879990    ... 0.518478    0.734022    0.308514    0.160481    0.180956
3   rvi 0.308932    0.398136    0.502806    0.232285    0.818337    ... 0.570697    0.672445    0.386451    0.467785    0.091396
4   rvi 0.326551    0.109473    0.121848    0.385493    0.109958    ... 0.180611    0.452464    0.317435    0.169633    0.257727
5   rvi 0.183643    0.023406    0.191923    0.158961    0.148543    ... 0.087721    1.557324    0.350104    0.548370    0.252558
5 rows × 600 columns
```

The conversion:

```
# Convert to XArray
rvi_df_t_xr = rvi_df_t.to_xarray()
type(rvi_df_t_xr)
Now, I want to normalise the data as follows:

# Get the RVI metric from the XArray
rvi = rvi_df_t_xr.metric.values

# Reshape the data into a 2D array
rvi_ss = rvi.reshape(-1, 1)

# Standardize the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
rvi_ss = scaler.fit_transform(rvi_ss)

# Reshape the standardized data back into an xarray
rvi_ss = xr.DataArray(rvi_ss.reshape(-1), coords=[rvi_df_t_xr.time], dims=['time'])

# Plot original data and standardized data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(rvi_df_t_xr, label='Original Data')
plt.plot(rvi_ss, label='Standardized Data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which yields:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'rvi'

When I want to check the values, I see:

```
rvi_df_t_xr.metric.values
array(['rvi'], dtype=object)
```

Maybe it's not a good idea to process the data as XArray (default format from the API) and would be better to convert to DataFrame anyway. I'm open to ideas.